# Is the function Lipschitz continuous on $ \overline{B_1(0)} $?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

$$ f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y+y^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$  $$ I \ know \ that \ it \ is \ continuous \ on\  \overline{B_1(0)} \ . \\ I\ think \ I \ have \ to \ show   \ ||f(x_1,x_2)-f(y_1,y_2)||\leq L||(x_1,x_2)-(y_1,y_2)|| \ , \ for \
x_i,y_i\in \overline{B_1(0)} \ ,\\i=1,2\ and \ L\in \mathbb{R}_+ $$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that $f(x,y) = y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: is it correct what I have to show ? $$ y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}* \sqrt{x^2+y^2} =yx^2+y^3 . $$

Comment: Yes, that's correct by definition of Lipschitz continuity. Note that it's enough to show that $f$ is differentiable and that its derivative is bounded in the disk.